# How to get folder path in Command Prompt stand by, not in C# Console App?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have created a C# Console App for use in Command Prompt.

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
    Console.WriteLine(path);
}
```

My result:
[image]

I want to get **C:\Users\Sophairk** instead of **C:\testswc**.

How to fix my code to get as what I want?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` then it will return the path of the executing .exe file.

Assuming that Sophairk is the username of your user, then you can do this:

```
 string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```

If it is the current directory that you want, then you can do this

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

You can check out the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-6.0

To see what other "Special Folders" are available.

Comment: This is what I want string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();